# Files getting corrupted even after writing in binary mode

Tags: c, sockets, client-server, binaryfiles, file-transfer

I am trying to send files(any type) from one PC(Client) to another PC(Server) in binary mode
but the program is working fine if I am running it on localhost between two terminals(videos, music everything working fine)

but, when I am running the client in a virtual machine(both machines on ubuntu 20.04) then the transferred file is getting corrupt(e.g. Receiving a Distorted image in the host after transfer).[corrupted image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AlVkP.jpg)

What should I do, I would be very grateful if someone could help me out.
[Full code](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=1ISK9afT80YExaWc7tvoo1SEbtht1FB5L)

Here I am attaching the code after the connection is established in TCP mode
*****Client.c******

```
write(sockfd, file_name, sizeof(file_name)); // send the file name to server


struct stat obj;

stat(file_name, &obj);
int file_size = obj.st_size;

write(sockfd, &file_size, sizeof(file_size)); // send the file size to server
system("clear");
printf("Sending %s .....\n\nFile size = %.3fkB\n",file_name,(1.0*file_size)/1024);

unsigned char buf[512]; // to store chunks of data from the target file
int count = file_size/512;
int remain = file_size % 512;

struct timeval start,end;
gettimeofday(&start,NULL);  //Starting time

while(count--){ // stores the data in buf array
    
    bzero(buf,512);
    fread(buf,1,sizeof(buf),f);
    // if(n == 512)
        write(sockfd,buf,sizeof(buf)); // send the data stored in buf to Server
}

// the last remaining chunk which is less than 512 Byte
if(remain){
    bzero(buf,512);
    fread(buf,1,remain,f);
    write(sockfd,buf,remain); // send the data stored in buf to Server
}

gettimeofday(&end,NULL);  //Ending time

double t1 =(end.tv_usec-start.tv_usec); //microseconds count
double time_taken= (end.tv_sec-start.tv_sec)+(t1/MILLION); // total time taken

printf("\n%s sent successfully\n",file_name);
printf("\n\n%lfsec taken.........\n",time_taken);

fclose(f); // close the file
close(sockfd); //close the socket

return 0;
```

*****Server.c******

```
// reading filename from the client side
bzero(file_name,512);
read(newsockfd,file_name,sizeof(file_name));

int file_size;
read(newsockfd,&file_size,sizeof(file_size));

FILE *fp;
fp = fopen(file_name,"wb");  // open corresponding file in write-binary mode

int count = file_size/512;
int remain = file_size%512;
unsigned char buf[512]; // to store a chunk of data coming from client file
system("clear");
printf("Recieving \"%s\" .....\n",file_name);

while(count--){
    bzero(buf,512); // clears the buf array
    read(newsockfd,buf,sizeof(buf)); // read the corresponding data coming from client to buf array
    fwrite(buf,1,sizeof(buf),fp); // write the corresponding data from buf array to file
}
// the last remaining chunk which is less than 512 Byte
if(remain){
    bzero(buf,512); // clears the buf array
    read(newsockfd,buf,remain); // read the corresponding data coming from client to buf array
    fwrite(buf,1,remain,fp); // write the corresponding data from buf array to file
}

// fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
printf("\n%s received successfully\n",file_name);
fclose(fp); // close the file
close(newsockfd); //close interconnected socket
close(sockfd); // close server socket
return 0;
```

}

Comment: `read(newsockfd,buf,sizeof(buf));` This is indicative of a common error. For streaming protocols like TCP you cannot assume the `read` will read exactly the amount you have requested. Need to check the return value of `read` to determine exactly how much data was actually read. Also, in general it is very bad form not to check the return value of function calls. Handling errors is an essential part of any robust coding and also aids greatly during debugging.

Comment: What should I do, if in case `read` is not reading the desired amount I have requested because at that time `fread` had already moved the file pointer 512 bytes ahead in the client-side file.

Comment: Did you get EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK error while writing into or reading from socket?  In that case you need to be in read/write loop for rest of the bytes. Beside that, don't  worry about partial read in server side where client may write 512 bytes at one go and vice versa.

Comment: No, I didn't get any error on running them. How should I know if there are such errors?

Comment: Just chek the return values of read()/write() functions wherever used in the code, if return == -1 then error happens ( ref: 'man read' ).  In your code, even if error occurs in read() you are still writing the buffer(partially filled or not filled) into the file, which may be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell, but it looks a lot like some extra data is being inserted into the middle of your image file. Since it happens in square blocks, I'm guessing your image file is a JPEG.

And this *might* be why:

```
read(newsockfd,buf,sizeof(buf)); // read UP TO 512 bytes
fwrite(buf,1,sizeof(buf),fp); // write EXACTLY 512 bytes
```

`read` asks for 512 bytes (the size of buf). But it might not read exactly 512 bytes. If you call `read` and there are no received bytes yet, it waits for some. But if there *are* some received bytes, but less than 512, it will return the ones it's received so far, and the return value tells you how many bytes it's returning.

Your program ignores this and writes 512 bytes, no matter how many were read.

You should only write the number of bytes that `read` says it read. And you should keep looping, until the total number of bytes matches the number you expect. Don't count the number of `read` calls, count the number of bytes.

Comment: Thanks man, this worked for me.

But I didn't get why this problem did not occur when transferring the same file on localhost

Comment: @Pirate25 on localhost there's no actual network so everything is simpler and maybe the computer doesn't have a reason to split up "packets"